# PDO connection try catch include

Tags: php, include, pdo, connection

I'm new to PDO and I wanna do it right from the beginning - I'm going to replace my old mysql_ functions on a site.

Have I got it right?:

Should I put the connection code in a try/catch and save it to a file, and include it on top of the page. Then put the queries in try/catch as well.

Or:

Should I put the connection code in a file and include it in the in the top of the try/catch statement above the query?

ver1:

```
include('pdo.php'); // try/catch in file

try { 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

ver2:

```
try {
    include('pdo.php'); // no try/catch in file

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Or should I put the try/catch in both places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do both and even more :

- Set an error handler that displays a message to the user and stops the PHP (see [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-error-handler.php))
- When you initiate the connexion, add a try/catch and throw an error if you catch an exception. Your website won't run without database connection i guess.
- Do a try/catch around your queries to recover gracefully from error (when you can)

Comment: Ok, but is it safe (meaning, - errors won't show username and password) to just use the try/catch on the connection? There is no chance that an exception thrown from a query-error displays connection info?

Comment: I've never seen any error displaying the password, sometimes password in debug mode. Best thing is to test (use `error_reporting(0)` when you're in production)

Comment: Ok.. What would be best about the connection then? Let's say you have a class with several methods, each having a sql-query. Is it best maybe to include $username and $password in the top of the page and then inside each try/catch, begin with: 

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);  
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

So you can start the connection and set it to null in each of the methods.

Comment: You just start your connection ONCE on the top of your page (in your includes for example) and re-use this connection after. Don't start a new connection for each query !

Comment: Yes but in a "Util" class with "free-standing" methods: checkUsername(), checkEmail() etc. If one call more than one of these methods on the same instance of the Util class, and have the connection in top of the page, once, - you can't set the connection to null inside the end of the method, this would leave the second method call on the same instance without a connection...

Comment: Just initialize it in the globals and don't disconnect ever (null the connection). PHP handles disconnections by itself when the script closes and actually reuses a connection between two pages to speedup the loading time.